# How to protect a port from attackers

Tags: port

I want to host a home server(i.e a minecraft one) which runs on port 25565. Is there a way to protect my home internet from attacks while this port is open? Or I should select an more unusual port? Maybe change it periodically could help but I am clueless.Sorry if the question is stupid but I am almost a complete beginner to network engineering.

Comment: You cannot “protect a port”. Apart from rate limiting and whatnot anyway. What you really need to secure is the application listening on that port.

Comment: If you could give a little bit more information how to do it would be great.

Comment: That depends almost entirely on the application in question. I’m not a Minecraft expert. There’s really only one general rule: Allow only the required set of privileges, if possible.

Comment: @Danielb you can absolutely protect a port - that is exactly what "deep packet inspection" on advanced firewalls does.

Comment: Yes, that’s a nice buzzword. But what exactly is a firewall supposed to do? At the very best, you could write an application-specific firewall that understands the protocol and tries to prevent malicious packets from reaching the application. That, in turn, makes your firewall vulnerable. And not only that: It won’t even work on encrypted connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security through obscurity is not the way to go, sure you can move it, but expect hackers to eventually find it.
First what OS are you running, and how many do you want have access to it?

You could create a white list of IP addresses with CIDR to allow a small group of friends access.

[PasswordProtect - Protect your server with a password](http://www.curse.com/bukkit-plugins/minecraft/passwordprotect) 
Obviously the longer and more complicated the better the password.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack -j ACCEPT  --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT  --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
iptables -A INPUT -i <internet facing NIC> -p tcp -m mulitport --dports 25565 -J ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i <internet facing NIC> -J DROP
```

If you have a web server or something else you need to add those ports, comma separated to the list.

Comment: For os I use arch linux. For the whitelist the server is not only for friends so that is a bad option